# C# Complex class construct Read/Set Value from JSON

Tags: c#, json, properties

I have a problem; I have various (too many) classes, that are linked as Parent/Child

I populate initially my top class while instantiate the others, as follows (works):

```
TopClass MyClass = new TopClass()
{
    Headers = new someHeaders()
    {
        CorrID = "1234567890",
        RequestID = "1234567890",
        L_Token = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    },
    Body = new someBody()
    {
        access = new AccessHeaders()
        {
            allPs = "allAcc",
            availableAcc = "all"
        },
        CombinedServiceIndicator = false,
        FrequencyPerDay = 10,
        ValidUntil = "2020-12-31"
    },
    ResponseAttributes = new ConsentResponse()
    {
        myId = String.Empty,
        myStatus = String.Empty,
        myName = String.Empty,
        _links_self_href = String.Empty,
        status_href = String.Empty
    }
};
```

The initials values that I populate above rarely change, but the Classes' properties change as the project goes on, and each class ends up having many properties.
I need to parse the properties and set values to any properties that match their name, but I can't seem to figure out why despite following official examples.
(I read the input data from a JSON string I use Newtonsoft - have tried everything out there)

I can't find a way to deserialize the JSON *and* assign any values to my properties *without* using the name of the property, i.e. without saying

```
MyClass.Body.access.allPs = "Hello"
```

but something like

```
var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();
var a = new { serverTime = "", data = new object[] { } };
var c = new JsonSerializer();
```

or

```
if (myresponse.Attributes.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(key) != null)
myresponse.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(key).SetValue(myresponse, entry.Value);
//and how do I read the value, parse my TopClass and assign the value to correct property?
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Values for the properties will get automatically assigned if the JSON is having the correct structure as per the class mentioned above.

Something like:

```
{
    "Body": 
           "access:
              {
                 "allPs" = "required value"
              }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < TopClass > (json );
```

Comment: Thank you, will try it, but, how do I populate my property afterwards? How can I iterate through all properties of the TopClass (and nested, linked etc) and find where is "allPs" and assign value "required value" ?

Comment: You can do this by reflection:

Comment: public void CopyValues<T>(T target, T source)
{
    Type t = typeof(T);

    var properties = t.GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.CanRead && prop.CanWrite);

    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        var value = prop.GetValue(source, null);
        if (value != null)
             prop.SetValue(target, value, null);
    }
}

Comment: Dear friend, you are on to something!!!!! I have my json as a string, as `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();` and my object say is called `TopClass` - may I ask how to use the method?